# Need Help Parsing File for This Pattern RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.024

Tags: regex, vb.net

Trying to parse a text file for records starting with an RH space and a date.  I need to return the entire line.  I expect to find about 6000 in the file.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of a full record:

RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.224 COA292 H393 2664FB753 178 -54.82  8.98      C 431 264 13    040 34 24.45-074 58 57.93      H

Snipit of text file:

> Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.292 JBU521 L536 1555FA320 089 -24.47  6.32      8 275 219 13    040 38 56.79-074 19 16.83                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.280 BTA2094L063 4142FE145 044 -35.94  8.82      P 257 135 3     040 38 42.65-074 34 44.99                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.372 1374479 479 1374FUNK  360 -44.41  16.89     # 385 241       040 44 33.76-074 48 06.66                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.456 1274230 230 1274FUNK  -01 -46.61  24.18     # 13  031       040 51 07.41-074 53 12.90                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.540 EJA691 S083 3354FC56X 108 -26.95  18.12     C 293 283 13    040 49 51.03-074 26 04.43                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.576 COA768 H592 1560FB753 029 -16.03  11.96     4 242 322 13    040 46 22.69-074 10 09.52      H                         Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.620 N3663B S211 3472FBE10 020 -22.72  19.23     5 161 228 10    040 51 54.68-074 20 58.46                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.684 N45002 S522 3525FPA31 030 -21.66  21.79     A 161 165 8     040 54 38.81-074 20 23.63                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.776 BTA2296L418 2615FE145 104 -21.82  28.5      C 323 357 13    041 01 08.25-074 22 39.48                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.832 CJC3304L450 2256FDH8D 070 -25.09  38.17     P 242 208 3     041 09 46.94-074 29 51.57                                Œ RH 09/27/08 11:49 11:49:00.836 N721AF S517 1553FPC12 111 -15.1   23.29     4 198 273 13    040 57 37.15-074 12 24.13                                Œ RH

Thanks!

Comment: Which programming language? Are there linebreaks in your file? Your example is formatted as if it was one single line.

Comment: And will the dates always be in the same format?

Comment: @Tim: I think the Œ characters may be filling in for line breaks.

Comment: Thought so, too, but I'd like to hear that from the OP.

Comment: Yes the dates will always be in the same format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you posted one long string, so you can split on "RH" using the split function on "RH", then iterate the items , split on spaces and check the first element using IsDate() eg assume "strContents" is the one long string sample.

```
data=Split(strContents,"RH")
For i=LBound(data) To UBound(data)
  s = Split(data(i)," ")  
  If IsDate(s(1)) Then
    WScript.Echo "RH"&data(i)
  End If 
Next
```

IsDate() checks for valid date.

Comment: Worked perfectly, tried doing this earlier strContents.split("RH") but it did not break the same as your method.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
^.*RH \d\d/\d\d\/\d\d.*$
```

will match a line that contains `RH`, space, and three double-digit groups separated by slashes.

In VB.NET, in order to iterate over all matches in a string:

```
Dim RegexObj As New Regex("^.*RH \d\d/\d\d/\d\d.*$", RegexOptions.Multiline)
Dim MatchResults As Match = RegexObj.Match(SubjectString)
While MatchResults.Success
    ' matched text: MatchResults.Value
    ' match start: MatchResults.Index
    ' match length: MatchResults.Length
    MatchResults = MatchResults.NextMatch()
End While
```

Comment: Tried to implement this, but it does not return any values.  Could be the language thing you mentioned above.